# NES- Command doesn't send to CommandHandler

Tags: nservicebus, cqrs, neventstore

My Command Class is as follows:

```
public class RegisterToConference : ICommand
    {
        public RegisterToConference()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.Seats = new Collection<SeatQuantity>();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

        public Guid ConferenceId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SeatQuantity> Seats { get; set; }          
    }
```

My Command Handler class is as follows:

```
public class OrderCommandHandler :
        IHandleMessages<RegisterToConference>
    {
        private readonly IRepository repository;
        private readonly IPricingService pricingService;

        public OrderCommandHandler(IRepository repository, IPricingService pricingService)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.pricingService = pricingService;
        }

        public void Handle(RegisterToConference command)
        {
            var items = command.Seats.Select(t => new OrderItem(t.SeatType, t.Quantity)).ToList();
            var order = repository.Get<Registration.Order>(command.OrderId);
            if (order == null)
            {
                order = new Registration.Order(command.OrderId, command.ConferenceId, items, pricingService);
            }
            else
            {
                order.UpdateSeats(items, pricingService);
            }

            repository.Add<Registration.Order>(order);
        }

    }
```

I send the command to bus from my controller's action method as follows:

```
this.commandBus.Send(command);
```

The End point configuration is as follows:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops, IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            LogManager.Use<Log4NetFactory>();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Wireup.Init()
                .UsingInMemoryPersistence()
                .EnlistInAmbientTransaction()
                .NES()
                .Build();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
        }

        public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
        {
            configuration.UseSerialization<Json>();
            configuration.EnableInstallers();
            configuration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
            configuration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
            configuration.PurgeOnStartup(false);
            configuration.RegisterComponents(c =>
            {
                c.ConfigureComponent<Repository>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork);

                });
        }

        public void Run(Configure config)
        {
            config.NES();
        }
    }
```

Inside the Web.config I configured as follows:

```
<configSections>
       <section name="TransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.TransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
   </configSections>

 <TransportConfig MaxRetries="5" MaximumConcurrencyLevel="1" MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond="0" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="Registration" Endpoint="Registration" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="RegistrationEndPoint.Errors" />
```

Inside Global.asax.cs I registered ISendOnlyBus as follows:

```
public static ISendOnlyBus Bus { get; private set; }
        private void RegisterBus()
        {
            var busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
            busConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
            busConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
            busConfiguration.Transactions().Disable();
            busConfiguration.PurgeOnStartup(false);

            LogManager.Use<NServiceBus.Log4Net.Log4NetFactory>();

            Bus = NServiceBus.Bus.CreateSendOnly(busConfiguration);
        }
```

When I click on button to send the command to command handler it doesn't work.

I am using NES.CQRS framework.

Comment: Did you start the bus in your Global.asax.cs? Do you have anything in the logs? do you have any messages in the queues?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved the issue. I had some problem regarded to dependency injection and I ignored it when I was suffered. Now I fixed ioc problem and it's now working fine.

Comment: For the rest of the community's benefit, would you either expand on what you did to fix it OR delete the question?